# can not createsuperuser becuase one column (foreignkey) can not be null in django

Tags: django

I have started a django project with extending User model from AbstractUser to my CustomUser model which have foreign key relation with other model. When I try to create superuser with manage.py it does not create a superuser. It shows an error -->
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'cid_id' cannot be null").

Any help will be appreciated

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField 

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Post(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='blog-default.png', upload_to='images/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # content = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cid = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='specialization') 
    approved = models.BooleanField('Approved', default=False)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

users/model.py

```
from django.db import models
from blog.models import Category
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser 

# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    cid = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default_person.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

cid in the Category model is the foreign key in the Post and CustomUser model. But when I try to createsuperuser it shows the error I mentioned above. cid can not be null for the user because when a user will register an account he has to select category in the registration form. But as the superuser don't have to register account using the registration form. So how do I have to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just give the ability to your `cid` to be `null`:

```
cid = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

In order to still have the `cid` field `required` for normal users you can try adjusting your `form`:

```
class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cid'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (...)
```

Otherwise if you are using plain html fields add `required` to your `input`.